# Remove Duplicate entries from XML files, based on the condition.

Tags: python, xml, duplicates, comparison, delete-row

I have a single list of long XML file with has list of data's. Based on "ID", I want to remove some nodes from the file. If ID value is repeated and doesn't have meta data, then I want to retain file node which has meta data and remove other.
IF same ID value is seen twice and both don't have meta data, then retain 1st one and remove 2nd.

Input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Def check="">
-<ID Elm="Front Sonar" ID="Opt-0001"/>

-<ID Elm="Rear Sonar" ID="Opt-0002">
<BlockID Wid="100" Auto="true"/>
<Check Auto="true" Siz="20" Nam="Fonts"/>
<Update Auto="true" Nam="Styles"/>
-<Updates Auto="true">
<Update Name="Type_1"/>
<Update Name="Type_21"/>
</Updates>
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Sonar Settings" ID="Opt-0003">
<BlockID Wid="80" Auto="true"/>
<Check Auto="true" Siz="2" Nam="Fun"/>
<Update Auto="true" Nam="done"/>
-<Updates Auto="true">
<Update Name="Type_31"/>
<Update Name="Type_2"/>
</Updates>
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Sonar" ID="Opt-0004">
<!-- no Elm reference found -->
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Menu" ID="ValOpt-0001">
<!-- no Elm reference found -->
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Cancel" ID="ValOpt-0002"/>
-<ID Elm="Go Home" ID="ValOpt-0003"/>
-<ID Elm="Group" ID="Opt-0001">
<!-- no Elm reference found -->
</ID>
-<ID Elm="School" ID="Opt-0002">
<!-- no Elm reference found -->
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Book" ID="Opt-0003">
<!-- no Elm reference found -->
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Lang" ID="ValOpt-0001">
<BlockID Wid="100" Auto="true"/>
<Check Auto="true" Siz="20" Nam="Fonts"/>
<Update Auto="true" Nam="Styles"/>
-<Updates Auto="true">
<Update Name="Type_1"/>
<Update Name="Type_21"/>
</Updates>
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Back" ID="ValOpt-0002">
<BlockID Wid="80" Auto="true"/>
<Check Auto="true" Siz="2" Nam="Fun"/>
<Update Auto="true" Nam="done"/>
-<Updates Auto="true">
<Update Name="Type_31"/>
<Update Name="Type_2"/>
</Updates>
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Exit" ID="ValOpt-0003"/>
</Def>
```

expected Output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Def check="">
-<ID Elm="Front Sonar" ID="Opt-0001"/>
-<ID Elm="Rear Sonar" ID="Opt-0002">
<BlockID Wid="100" Auto="true"/>
<Check Auto="true" Siz="20" Nam="Fonts"/>
<Update Auto="true" Nam="Styles"/>
-<Updates Auto="true">
<Update Name="Type_1"/>
<Update Name="Type_21"/>
</Updates>
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Sonar Settings" ID="Opt-0003">
<BlockID Wid="80" Auto="true"/>
<Check Auto="true" Siz="2" Nam="Fun"/>
<Update Auto="true" Nam="done"/>
-<Updates Auto="true">
<Update Name="Type_31"/>
<Update Name="Type_2"/>
</Updates>
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Sonar" ID="Opt-0004">
<!-- no Elm reference found -->
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Cancel" ID="ValOpt-0002"/>
-<ID Elm="Go Home" ID="ValOpt-0003"/>
-<ID Elm="Group" ID="Opt-0001">
<!-- no Elm reference found -->
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Lang" ID="ValOpt-0001">
<BlockID Wid="100" Auto="true"/>
<Check Auto="true" Siz="20" Nam="Fonts"/>
<Update Auto="true" Nam="Styles"/>
-<Updates Auto="true">
<Update Name="Type_1"/>
<Update Name="Type_21"/>
</Updates>
</ID>
-<ID Elm="Back" ID="ValOpt-0002">
<BlockID Wid="80" Auto="true"/>
<Check Auto="true" Siz="2" Nam="Fun"/>
<Update Auto="true" Nam="done"/>
-<Updates Auto="true">
<Update Name="Type_31"/>
<Update Name="Type_2"/>
</Updates>
</ID>
</Def>
```

using Element tree, I tried checking for 
if line starteswith ""
    #remove elemet from list.
else
    print "Element has meta data"
but unfortunately my function is not entering the loop itself.... I always get print statement under else condition. Any help regarding this????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected output still has some duplicates. The output from following code is different than expected but it actually removes all duplicates:

```
from lxml import etree

xml_input = 'Input.xml'
xml_output = 'Output.xml'

with open(xml_input) as xml:
   root = etree.XML(xml.read())

#create dictionary where key is an ID and value is a list of nodes with the ID
node_dict = {}
for node in root.xpath('//*[@ID]'):
   try:
      node_dict[node.get('ID')].append(node)
   except KeyError:
      node_dict[node.get('ID')] = [node]

for key, nodes in node_dict.iteritems():
   #find all nodes with childs
   nodes_with_childs = [node for node in nodes if len(node.xpath('./*')) > 0]

   #leave only first node with childs, remove other nodes
   if len(nodes_with_childs) > 0:
      for node in set(nodes) - set([nodes_with_childs[0]]):
         node.getparent().remove(node)
   else:
      #leave only first node, remove other nodes
      for node in nodes[1:]:
         node.getparent().remove(node)

with open(xml_output, 'w') as xml:
   xml.write(etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True))
```

Comment: Found 1 problem... Some of text in node has special characters... While coping XML files can see some junk value for special characters... How can this be handled???

Comment: I have a line something like this in my Input.xml  file

“<ID Elm="Starting Apple CarPlay…" ID="Car 0010" >”

After removal of duplicate entries and copying the content to output.xml, its value changes to

 

<ID " Elm="Starting CarPlay&#823 ID="Car 0010;">

Comment: Please, add another question and add more info. It is hard to say anything just like this, without knowing what you do exactly.